# Facebook Web Hosting not working properly

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-canvas, unity-webgl

I am developing an Unity game for Facebook Canvas. I am using the Facebook Webhosting product. Everything is setup on in the app settings both in game and on the developer's app page, but when I try to load the game by using the Facebook Web Games Page URL I get the following error: "The requested URL was not found on this server" (please see the attached picture).

[image: Facebook Canvas Screenshot]

[What could it be the problem? I followed every step in setting up the project, the page, the Webhosting product (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/services/contenthosting).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8g8XO.png)

Comment: This has been buggy for a couple of days now, there have been several reports on the FB bug tracker.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I compressed files to .7z with a different software and it worked for me.